# Error when building the AOSP for Hikey970

Tags: android-source

I hava followed this tutorial to build the AOSP for Hikey970 :
https://github.com/neonVoice/hikey970-aosp-build
but when i build the project ( make -j4 ) it give me this error:

**device/linaro/hikey/wpan/uim/Android.mk: error: uim: LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng is obsolete**

**build/make/core/base_rules.mk:171: eroor: done.**

does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

have a try to use # to shield it，some version like android 10 seems not to use t